# Sync Adapter run only once after connection restored

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I'm trying to implement `SyncAdapter`, it works almost correctly like I want it. 
 The only problem is that when the user is offline and the periodic sync is called(ex: 10 times), when the user recovers the internet connection, the sync adapter call will repeat for 10 times:

How I call it on button press:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
bundle.putString(SYNC_TRIGGER_SOURCE, SyncManager.FROM_SYNC_CLICK);
ContentResolver.requestSync(account, AUTHORITY_PONTOTEL, bundle);
```

If the user changes their connection to offline, clicks on the button 293879878923792387 times, when he turns the connection back to online, it will call the server 293879878923792387 (x 50000 users, the server will be ddosed ;|)

Is there a way to avoid this without locking the button?

Is there a way to CLEAR the sync queue and keep only the last one?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to CLEAR the sync queue and keep only the last one?

Actually, this should be the default behavior. Provided that you request the sync with the same arguments and for the same account, it will cancel any previously queued syncs before queuing the new request, or not queue it at all if there is a sync with the same arguments already running. (if you'd like to have a look yourself, you can check the source code of `SyncManager`, where they will compare keys and bundles to remove duplicates)

This said, I would advise you to make sure to verify how and where you request a sync. If you use the same account and add the same arguments to your `Bundle`, then it should only run *one* sync, ignoring further requests with the same payload.

It might be that `SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED` overrides the mentioned behavior in some way, so I'd try to run your code without the flag and see if that fixes it, although I don't see any signs of this in the SDK 26 source code.

And as a last resort you could use `cancelSync` to cancel all syncs for an Account, but I don't believe that this will be necessary.